# Can the Kinect 2 be used in Linux?

Tags: linux, open-source, kinect

I know there are open source implementations available to program Kinect version 1 applications in Linux, can Kinect version 2 be used in these as well. or are there any other methods to use Kinect v2 with Linux?

Comment: And which part of your question has to do with electrical engineering?

Comment: The drivers would have to be updated to support the Kinect v2 for those implementations to work

Comment: Open-source driver: https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2